# aws opsworks multiple nodejs apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I have one OpsWorks Nodejs Stack. I setup multiple nodejs apps. The problem now is that all nodejs server.js scripts listens on port 80 for amazon life check but the port can be used only by one. 
I dont know how to solve this. I have read amazon documentation but could not find the solution. I read that I could try to change deploy recipe variables to set this life check to different port but it didn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I battled with this issue for a while and eventually found a very simple solution.

---

The port is set in the deploy cookbook's attributes...

https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/deploy/attributes/deploy.rb

by the line...

```
default[:deploy][application][:nodejs][:port] = deploy[:ssl_support] ? 443 : 80
```

you can override this using the stack's custom json, such as:

```
{
  "deploy" : {
    "app_name_1": {
      "nodejs": {
        "port": 80
      }
    },
    "app_name_2": {
      "nodejs": {
        "port": 3000
      }
    }
  },
  "mongodb" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

Now the monitrc files at /etc/monit.d/node_web_app-.monitrc should reflect their respective ports, and monit should keep them alive!

Comment: how would I forward different domains/subdomains on port 80

ex: 
dom1.example.com:80 => app_name_1:80
dom2.example.com:80 => app_name_1:3000

Comment: @ToliZaslavskiy I haven't played with subdomains in opsworks, but I know there is a subdomain setting for each App. You could also create a separate load balancer in EC2 that points to http://domain:3000 to hit your app running on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to implement life check node service that is listening on port 80. When amazon life check request is made to that service it responds and execute its own logic to check for health of all services. It works great.